# Converting a list from LocalDate to Javascript Date in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

How can I convert a list from LocalDate to a List of Javascript Dates in thymeleaf?

When I just add the list in

```
var timeaxis = /*[[${timeaxis}]]*/ [];
```

then I get a conversion of the LocalDate to JSON

```
var timeaxis = [{'chronology':{'calendarType':'iso8601','id':'ISO'},'dayOfMonth':1,'dayOfWeek':{'$type':'DayOfWeek','$name':'TUESDAY'},'dayOfYear':306,'era':{'$type':'IsoEra','$name':'CE'},'leapYear':true,'month':{'$type':'Month','$name':'NOVEMBER'},'monthValue':11,'year':2016}];
```

When I try to formatting the the Dates with https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time

```
var timeaxis = /*[[${#temporals.listFormat(timeaxis, "'new Date('yyyy','MM','d')'")}]]*/ [];
```

then I get an array of strings

```
var timeaxis = ['new Date(2016,11,1)'];
```

What I would like to have is `[new Date(2016,11,1)]` how can I achieve this in Thymeleaf?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this... in thymeleaf 3, I'm getting: `var timeaxis = [new Date(2017,02,10), new Date(2017,02,10), new Date(2017,02,10)];`.  Are you using thymeleaf 2?

Comment: @Metroids thanks for your answer. I was using thymeleaf 2. I also tried it with thymleaf 3.0.1 and it still does not work. With thymeleaf 3 I get: `[{"year":2016,"month":"NOVEMBER","dayOfMonth":1,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","era":"CE","dayOfYear":306,"leapYear":true,"monthValue":11,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}]`

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question but it's still valid. So here's my solution which I think satisfies OP's demands. Using Thymeleaf 3:

```
    const nonWorkingDays = [];
    [# th:each="date : ${#temporals.listFormat(nonWorkingDaysFromDb, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"]
    nonWorkingDays.push(new Date([[${date}]]));
    [/]
```

it results as:

```
    const nonWorkingDays = [];

    nonWorkingDays.push(new Date("2019-01-01"));
    nonWorkingDays.push(new Date("2019-02-01"));
```

**Caveat:**

[image: Warning note on MDN Date page of dateString section]

See [Javascript Date docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

If you want to create the date with local timezone then following will do:

```
    const nonWorkingDays = [];
    [# th:each="date : ${nonWorkingDays}"]
    nonWorkingDays.push(new Date([[${date.year}]], [[${date.monthValue - 1}]], [[${date.dayOfMonth}]], 0, 0, 0));
    [/]
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, until a better answer is found, I solve the problem in javascript

```
var timeaxis = /*[[${#temporals.listFormat(timeaxis, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}]]*/ [];
var dates = $.map(timeaxis, function (date) {
    var parts = date.split('-');
    //please put attention to the month (parts[0]), Javascript counts months from 0:
    // January - 0, February - 1, etc
    return new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]);
});
```